# Can a person burden himself more than what it can take?

Tags: practical-islam, tafseer

I know very well that nothing happens except by the will of Allah. I also know sometimes we have to face the consequence of our sins.

I also know according to Quran:

> لَا يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا
>
> “Allah does not burden a soul beyond that it can bear…” (Qur’an, 2:286).

So I want to know is it possible for a person to burden himself more than it can bear by doing sins or things that can lead him to problems and stress which he will be unable to bear.

Comment: First of, it wouldn’t make sense. Let me give you an example, if I were to put you to lift 10Kg, but you only can lift 2Kg, will you succeed?

Comment: @YoungMuslim1000 This looks like a hypothetical or philosophical question. As the OP says nothing happens except by the will of Allah. Then why ask of an alternate scenario when it is not possible?

Comment: "So I want to know is it possible for a person to burden himself more than it can bear by doing sins or things that can lead him to problems and stress which he will be unable to bear." The question lacks a focus and needs to be clarified as the verse is about Allahs orders, you are now asking about a person that burden himself but you didn't specify whether the problems this person may have are interpersonal or on judgement day. You may also ask whether doing this is a sin, but as is the question is unclear and therefore not reasonably answerable unless one has guessed what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As‘salaamu alaikum, brother.

What does “not being able to bear” look like? Is it having a nervous breakdown? Being shellshocked? Going insane? Does it mean losing ones fighting spirit? Giving up and committing suicide?

We know that distressed people sometimes experience and/or do the things I mentioned above, but I believe that, when Allah says to us that there is no burden that we can‘t bear, He is assuring us that we  don‘t have to break down under stress. We can endure.

In Surat-ul-Balad (90), ayat 4, Allahu ta ‘aala says,  “Truly, we have created man into toil and struggle.” And we know that Allah is Al-Musaw‘wir - when He ordains a purpose or a certain task for a creature of His, He fashions that creature to make it excellently suited to fulfill its purpose/task.

So if we were created into toil and struggle then it necessarily follows that we are built to endure all the rigors of toil and struggle.

However, the capacity to bear every burden exists within us as a latent ability. It it rare for someone to be able to function and remain effective under high stress without any previous education, training, and conditioning.

Once the ability cope under high stress has been developed then we become very resilient. We are then able to deal with all kinds of hardship, NO MATTER THE SOURCE, (i.e., even when the hardship is the result of our own foolishly sinful behavior).

Now, let me back up what I‘m saying with proofs....

There are a number of ayah in the Qur‘an where Allah refers to a group of kuffaar as being “given to vehement warfare”, meaning these are a people who function well and are highly effective within the chaotic, high-stress fog of war. A couple of examples:

17:4-7, the Babylonians and then the Romans which he sent against the Banu Israa‘eel when they became rebellious against Him.

27:32-33, the army of Bilqis, Queen of Sheeba.

These were mushrikeen He was referring to. Their kufr and shirk alone had them deep in sin, yet because of their training and conditioning, they were able to bear the burden of warfare very well. I don‘t know much about Bilqis and her people, but it is well known that the ancient Babylonians and the Roman after them were both a conquering people. And the Romans were homosexuals on top of  being kuffaar  and mushrikeen.

My point in saying that is to illustrate that our sinfulness does not deprive us of the ability to bear burdens once we have properly developed the ability.

In closing, let me emphasize to you that I believe the amazing capacity to bear burdens applies only to this Dunya.
In the Akhirah Allah is going to heap burdens on those He remains angry with that are defintely going to overwhelm them.

Rasulullah (a.s.) said that our sins will be a burden on the Day of Judgment, and he admonished his Sahabah, “so don‘t let me see you at Judgment carrying somone‘s cow (presumably stolen while they were in the Dunya) on your head.” Speaking of wrongdoers Allah says,

“Let them bear, on the Day of Judgment, their  own burdens in full, and also the burdens of those without knowledge, whom they mislead. Alas, how grievious the burdens they will bear!” Qur‘an 16:25

And we know that the agony of the Hellfire is a burden that is going to break the spirit of all who go there.

I  hope this helps you, brother.

Ma‘as‘salaam.

Comment: I just read @Honey‘s answer. She answered from the perspective of “burdens” being the duties that Allah has placed upon us. If we are physically or financially unable to fulfill a duty then we are excused from that obligation. That is a correct answer, (and may Allah reward her for it). I answered from the perspective of a “burden” being a very stressful challenge to face or a difficulty to go through BECAUSE OF HOW YOU POSED THE QUESTION. How did you mean the word “burden” ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes a person can do such harm to himself. The verse is talking about Allah.

It is not talking about yourself. You could bring misery to yourself. Everything that happens in this world is by Allah's *permission*. But not everything happening is *pleasing* to him. Man killing his messengers or disobeying his commands are acts that he gives permission (so our world won't be a pre-destined limited world). Yet Allah is not pleased with them.

Similarly harming yourself is not something Allah is pleased with. If fasting is harmful to you then you're not suppose to fast. Is standing up and praying is harmful to you then you're not suppose to stand and pray. You should pray sitting. That being said a hot-head Muslim can fast while he's sick and bring harm to himself. Allah won't freeze him for doing that.

Answer (score -2):

According to my logic, it doesn’t make sense for you to ask God to give you something you want but you can’t handle it, as God Says in Quran:

> ”God does not burden a soul much than he can.”

Which it means, if you were to ask Him to give you something much greater and you know you can’t handle it, and God knows you can’t handle this, then He won’t give you the thing you want, because He knows what’s the best for you. He Said Himself in Quran that He is: **All-Wise** and **All-Knowing** and **The Most Just**

When He See that you actually can handle something much greater and heavier, then He’ll give you something which you can handle.

Don’t act as if you know better for you, because like this you show superiority to God. Remember how I bliss refused to bow to Adam after God requested to bow immoderately to Adam to angels including I-bliss? And I bliss told God, **”why to bow to Adam when we are made from fire and he’s made from clay?** and so, God got angry at I bliss and punished him.

So, you are doing the same as he by wishing for God to give you something much greater.

And the thing with committing sins, that’s not good. You are going against God on purpose. If you want to have a happy life, then stay away as much as possible from sins and seek refuge from God against sins. Seek His protection from committing sins. Do you want to have a happy life? Or a miserable life? It’s all up to you. I choose a happy life.

And if you want happy life, stay away from sins, do which God is pleased, repent!!!

Do you want a miserable life? Do sins much greater, don’t seek His forgiveness! Like this you can have a miserable life.

What do you think? Do I make sense?
I hope this answer is the answer you’re looking for.

Comment: Why did I got down vote?